# Move files based on filename using command prompt

Tags: cmd, move

I am trying to move files from a location to another one based on filename ONLY by using command line. The below works pretty fine but I do not want to specify both, the file name and the extension:

```
MOVE C:\firstlocation\file.sdltm "C:\secondlocation\file.sdltm"
```

The reason behind this is that I have the following files in the *firstlocation*:

1. file.sdltm
2. file.tmx

and my aim is to move both files named "file" to the *secondlocation* regardless the extension.

Sorry if this question has been asked before, - couldn't find any that matches my criteria.

Comment: `move "C:\firstlocation\file.*" "C:\secondlocation\file.*"`?

Comment: Thanks for leading to the right direction. This worked (removed the filename from the second path):

move "C:\firstlocation\file.*" "C:\secondlocation"

Comment: Correct @FrenciRama, however, had you entered `move /?` at the Command Prompt, you'd have seen the usage information for your problematic command. This clearly shows the syntax for moving one or more files as `MOVE [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination`, where `[drive:][path]filename1` specifies the location and name of the file or files you want to move; and `destination` specifies the new location of the file. The destination can consist of a drive letter and colon, a directory name, or a combination, i.e. `MOVE "drive:\path\filename1" "drive letter:\directory name"`.